# password_hash is not working

Tags: php, passwords

I have developed a site. Before that there is another site we need to merge all db from old site to new site. In old site for login they have used **password_hash()**. we also used **password_hash()**. when we are registered as new user, its login is working fine when we check login we used **password_verify('password', "saved_hash_in_db")**.

Why existing user are not able to login with same **password_hash()** algorithm?

They have used the below code.

hash function while register

```
$password = "123456";
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

check function while login

```
password_verify($password , $theHash);
```

> $theHash stored in db while register

Please tell me how can I fix this issue?

Comment: It should work. Did one of those sites use some salt or something? Or was it pre php5.5 and they rolled their own password_hash function?

Comment: They don't use any salt. i don't know which verssion php they had used.
is there any problem is php version is different? if yes, please tell me what is problem.

Comment: To add on to what @MagnusEriksson said, many factors can cause this problem, like the PHP version of both sites, the implementation of code or even more.

What does help, is perhaps you could show us an excerpt of your authentication code?

Comment: `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` was introduced in PHP 5.5. So if they used those functions in an earlier version, they would need to have added those functions. And in that case, depending on the implementation, it could have generated a totally different type of hash.

Comment: i don't know exactly which php version they had used. please check my question i have edited their exact code. i am sure they have used 5.5 or higher version for php. otherwise password_hash() should not work.

Comment: Try with several exact passwords. Maybe there is problem with encoding in your db?

Comment: Ony to make sure, do you do anything with the result of `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`, I cannot see an assignment to a variable, or do you maybe think the variable `$password`contains the hash afterwards?